# CiscoNAC - Improving auth timing and user experience

Tags: cisco, local-area-network, access-control-list

I am looking into improving user experience with Cisco NAC.

At the moment, after any login, users experience annoying SSL warning from different softwares connecting via https. The traffic is redirected to the NAC appliance and the name mismatch as illustrated below, after authentication (about 1 minute), the traffic go through normally. 
[image]

A few questions:

- Is there a way to pre-authenticate user before Windows logging ? (After all user can auto-connect and authenticate to WiFi before logon).
- Can startup items be hold/greyed out/delayed until NAC is done with granting access ?
- Can NAC caches authentication for 30 minutes or an hour (Like an HTTP cookie) or a token system valid for a while ? At the moment, disconnecting and reconnecting a laptop to Ethernet start the authentication process from scratch.

**Update - 08-05-2017:
Months after the implementation, the solution happens to be very painful and is counter-productive. We're about to decommission it. Computers fail to authenticate against NAC, thus employees cannot access local resources. NAC increases our security posture but cannot justify the loss of productivity.**

> *Security at the expense of usability comes at the expense of security*

Comment: That is an `office365` question which you should ask your vendor.  They have a complex way of dealing with this which is beyond any support you could get by hiding your domain name.

Comment: Hello Julie, thank you for your reply. This isn't related to Office365 only, but also a VPN agent, a text expander looking for updates, and two other softwares connecting through https. I think the resolution would relates to configuring NAC properly if the product allows it (unless it is a crapy solution)

Comment: To solve your problem, you'll need to clarify (even to yourself), why the NAC shows the Office 365 certificate.

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstand. The client or "end-user" connects to https:// outlook.office365.com but the traffic is intercepted by cisconac and present cisco nac certificate. Therefore the certificate name mismatches. On the left side the same happens with the vpn Agent which tries to connect to https:// .vpn.mydomain.tld

Comment: That is very justified then and by SSL design, you can not bypass that security warning unless you manually put exceptions on the clients.

Comment: Yes, again, this is why I am not looking at specific application settings but at configuring NAC to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Your users should not go through your proxy to reach Office 365.  That is the issue.  I still don't understand your setup but you may have to change routing rules to solve it.

Comment: There is no proxy here. I believe you do not know what a NAC (Network Access Control) device is intended for. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I do not know the NAC, but I know exactly why you get that error.  Your NAC is apparently intercepting a HTTPS connection.

Comment: Yes, I understand as well why I get these errors. This is to be expected. This post, and associated questions have nothing to do with explaining how SSL works.

Comment: As soon as NAC authenticate the user, it does not present its certificate anymore and let the traffic go through, this is why the post is named "Improving authentication timing and user experience". It is the principle behind NAC

Comment: @FlorianBidabe Please post your update as an answer and mark it accepted. The edit does not belong in the question. There is even an achievement for self-answer.